# unknown query engine error with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, vb6

I hope I'm following protocol on this post as for this is my first post but I need some guidance here. I'm not for sure what else to try but here it is.

-- We have an in house program written in VB6 that uses crystal reports 9 (v9.2.0.448). Everything works perfectly fine until I try to do a stored procedure inside the crystal report. When the report is being brought up through the crystal viewer...it gives me the error/message : "unknown query engine error". I'm getting random results when I try to run the report inside of the application(some fields are showing perfectly fine when on the report(the non-pivoted fields, other fields(pivot fields) in the same SP(SP1) cause the error(another time it'll run/another time it wont. I went through and placed every field on there individually, saved the report, ran the program to see which threw the error and which didn't. At one point, some of the pivoted fields showed up in one SP1, but when I went back to that field, it decided not to show up. The other SP(SP2), no pivoted field wanted to work...I don't know how to explain this any better without going into a story). The SP's work perfectly fine in SQL Manager. I get the results I want. The SP's work perfectly fine in the Crystal Designer, everything shows..no errors. Here is what the tables look like:

--> table : ticketfactorDT

```
TicketID ~ DrectionType ~ TicketSeries ~ SeriesCatagory~ FactorID ~ FactorValue

554559   ~ I            ~ GRAIN       ~ grain ~ BCFM     ~ 0 

554559   ~ I            ~ GRAIN       ~ grain ~ DMG     ~ 0

554559   ~ I            ~ GRAIN       ~ grain ~ MST.     ~ 15

554559   ~ I            ~ GRAIN       ~ grain ~ T.W.     ~ 56
```

--> table : commodity

```
CommodID ~ FactorID ~ FactorOrder

CY ~ BCFM ~ 4

CY ~ DMG ~ 3

CY ~ Dock ~ 5

CY ~ MST. ~ 2

CY ~ T.W. ~ 1
```

--> SP1 :

TicketID ~ TSeries ~ SCat ~ DType ~ 0 ~ 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ 5 ~ 6 ( <-- factor order #)

554559 ~ GRAIN ~ grain ~ I ~ NULL ~ 56 ~ 15 ~ 0 ~ 0 ~ NULL ~ NULL

--> SP2 :

CID ~ 0 ~ 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ 5 ~ 6 ( <-- factor order #)

CY ~ NULL ~ T.W. ~ MST. ~ DMG ~ BCFM ~ Dock ~ NULL

```
SP1 = 

SELECT @col2 = ISNULL(@col2 + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(FactorOrder) 
FROM (SELECT distinct FactorOrder  FROM Factor) as Factors;
```

--select @col2

```
SET @sql2 = N'SELECT TicketID, TicketSeries, SeriesCatagory, DirectionType, ' + @col2 + '
             from (SELECT T.TicketID, T.TicketSeries, T.SeriesCatagory, T.DirectionType, FactorValue, FactorOrder
                   FROM (Factor FT INNER JOIN TicketFactorDT TFD ON FT.FActorID = TFD.FactorID) INNER JOIN Tickets T ON T.TicketID = TFD.TicketID AND T.TicketSeries = TFD.TicketSeries AND T.SeriesCatagory = TFD.SeriesCatagory AND T.DirectionType = TFD.DirectionType) factor
             Pivot ( 
                max(FactorValue) 
                for FactorOrder In(' + @col2 + '))as ordr;'

exec sp_executesql @sql2

SP2 = 

----GIVES ME THE FACTOR IDS FROM FACTOR TABLE BASED ON FACTOR ORDER

DECLARE @sql1 as nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @col1 as nvarchar(2000);

SELECT @col1 = ISNULL(@col1 + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(FactorOrder) 
FROM (SELECT distinct f.FactorOrder  FROM Factor F inner join Commodity C on c.CommodityID = f.CommodityID) as Factors;

--select @col1

SET @sql1 = N'Select CommodityID, ' + @col1 + '
             from (Select FT.CommodityID, FT.factorId, factorOrder 
                   From (Factor FT INNER JOIN TicketFactorDT TFD ON FT.FActorID = TFD.FactorID)) factor
             Pivot ( 
                max(FactorID) 
                for FactorOrder In(' + @col1 + '))as odr;'

exec sp_executesql @sql1
```

--> Sorry for the long post. I hope this isn't to confusing but I tried to give as much info to help understand. I've been at this for the past 2-3days now just to come away with an error message that I don't know what/how to fix and it is extremely frustrating. IF anyone has any ideas, tips, things to try, things I'm doing wrong, anything will help. lol. I'm just lost on this one

Inhouse program is windows form VB6.

Crystal reports: 9, version up above

Sql manager studio 2012

Report database type is OLE DB(ADO)

Report Provider is SQLOLEDB

My machine has Crystal 8, 9, 11 & 13(I believe)...have the newest engine packs

Comment: I would like to add to this...I am not the programmer so I cant walk through the code but work very closely with him...so I can suggest things to try..I have mainly been the crystal report writer

Comment: Run a profiler trace and verify that the application is sending the SQL queries you expect.

Comment: when you say run a profiler trace....what do you mean? I found the SQL profiler and running a trace on the server...is that right?.

Comment: Yes exactly.   With a trace running you can see if your application is sending the right queries to your SQL Server.

Comment: ok, cool! so when the trace is done running(out putting it to a file), what do I look for? btw, my trace has been running since noon. :( there were a lot of database's on that server instance

Comment: Look for a query that came from your application.   The actual query will be in the "TextData" column.   You will be able to see what parameters were passed by your application and verify that it is sending the correct values to SQL server.   You can copy the query from Profiler, paste it in to SSMS, and verify that it returns the values you expect.   You can see if you are sending the query to the right server and the right database, under the right SQL Login, etc.

Comment: ok.so, first off...sorry for no response  in awhile....but in the profiles I have run, I haven't seen my query...I've let them run quite awhile and they get prematurely end b/c of network disconnections or something...but so far...from what I have ran...I haven't seen my query...I even limited down to only that database on that server

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that your app isn't able to connect to your database to send it a query.   Can't you start a trace and then run through the app yourself so that you know exactly when a query should be sent from it?

Comment: ok so...I finally got a sql trace worth something to me, if I just would of knew how it fully worked...lol..my bad. What seems to happen, in my opinion is that when I run it in crystal hooked to a different database, save it, and try to run it in the application...it throws a fit "unknown query engine error". When I update the crystal report in the designer to the actual database, then save it an run it in the application....It works fine it looks like. No error, yet anyways. Does that mean I have to ALWAYS do the report in the designer with the exact database for a stored procedure?

Comment: b/c if so...the database will change at some point with out me knowing on the clients end...example - adding or removing a field. That is what the stored procedure is supposed to do/take care of, dynamic adding of fields and flattening out a table for easier reporting. Obviously it wont add/remove the fields on the report, I would have to update that but that'll mean i'll have to update the stored procedure on their end for any change and that might cause issues..idk. if I'm understanding this correctly

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding it either, and I don't work with Crystal so I don't know what its limitations are.   Not sure what you mean by "When I update the crystal report in the designer to the actual database" or by "ALWAYS do the report in the designer with the exact database for a stored procedure?"    I mean, as opposed to what?   The wrong database?

Comment: sorry, what I mean is in the crystal designer, you can connect to a server and a specific database. way I've always done reports was connect to a server and database that has good amount of data in it to test on. It doesn't HAVE to be the exact(name...just similar tables/fields) database that's going to be out there on the clients machine b/c the application is supposed to update that string anyways. what I did was connected Crystal to say SERVER1\Datbase1 and saved it. The application though looks at SERVER2\Database1...same DB, just different servers

Comment: the application will update that report connections string from SERVER1\Database1 to SERVER2\Database1. now, with all the being said...I looked at it again this morning...and couldn't get it to fail like it was last week. Not doing anything different, that I can tell. The application runs with all data showing, I don't get it and I've probably confused anyone that's looked at this post...lol...sorry